# Google Cloud - Download large file from web

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download GhTorrent dump from http://ghtorrent-downloads.ewi.tudelft.nl/mysql/mysql-2020-07-17.tar.gz which is about 127gb

I tried in the cloud but after 6gb it stops, I believe that there is a size limit for using curl

```
curl http://ghtorrent... | gsutil cp - gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/mysql-2020-07-17.tar.gz
```

I cannot use Data Transfer as I need to specify the url, size in bytes (which I have) and hash MD5 which I don't have and I only can generate by having the file in my disk. I think(?)

Is there any other option to download and upload the file directly to the cloud?
My total disk size is 117gb sad beep

Comment: The bad news is this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/504. However, it is obvious that when you run the `curl url | gsutil cp <bucket>`, the traffic goes through your local machine anyway, so in terms of ingress/egress efficiency it is the same as downloading the file locally and then copying the file to the bucket using `gsutil`

Comment: It's more sad that that request was 2 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me with Storage Transfer Service: https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/

Have a look on the pricing before moving TBs especially if your target is nearline/coldline: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/pricing

---

Simple example that copies a file from a public url, to my bucket using a `Transfer Job`:

- Create a file *theTsv.tsv* and specify the complete list of files that must be copied. This example contains just one file:

```
TsvHttpData-1.0
http://public-url-pointint-to-the-file
```

- Upload the *theTsv.tsv* file to your bucket or any publicly accessible url. In this example I am storing my `.tsv` file on my bucket `https://storage.googleapis.com/<my-bucket-name>/theTsv.tsv`
- <kbd>Create a transfer job</kbd> - <kbd>List of object URLs</kbd>

  - Add the `url` that points to the *theTsv.tsv* file in the `URL of TSV file` field;
- Select the target bucket
- Run immediately

[image]

[image]

My file, named `MD5SUB` was copied from the source `url` into my bucket, under an identical directory structure.

Comment: The problem with storage transfer is that I need to specify the MD5 hash of the file

Comment: if you have access on the source server, or if you can ask the uploader to calculate it... `openssl md5 -binary mysql-2020-07-17.tar.gz | openssl enc -base64`

Comment: I did it. I am editing the answer in 2 min. The MD5 and the size seem to be optional in the .tsv file

Comment: Please leave a comment if you are going to attempt to move the 100GB+ using this method and if it worked. Also, please let me know if I can turn off the sharing on the theTsv3.tsv that's shared in my bucket, when you no longer need it. I'll also edit the answer to be generic. Thank you!

Comment: How did you created the tsv? I keep getting this error,  
Details: First line in URL list must be TsvHttpData-1.0 but it is: <!doctype html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><base href="https://accounts.google.com/">....
BTW, I was able to download your test

Comment: the file must have the .tsv extension. The content is exactly as I pasted it under the first step: 2 rows, first row the tsv format, second row the url. After creating the file, I uploaded it somewhere in my bucket. Granted public access on it. Copied the public url. Pasted the public url in the _Url of tsv file_ << here you are asked for a url to the file, not the file itself

Comment: I want to clean up my answer and replace the direct links to my personal bucket with hard-typed examples. Do you still need the files that are shared in my bucket? BTW, Have you tried to transfer the 100GB+ file and how did it go?

Comment: Yes! the issue I had was because I did not set the tsv file as public, once I did it work as a charm

Comment: How long did it take for a 100GB file? I just tried it but bandwith for average transfer speed was too low -2-3mb/s.